# Reed-Solomon encoding in GF2?

Tags: finite-fields, coding-theory

I'm vaguely familiar with Reed-Solomon encoding + know that it's generally done in GF(256).

Is there any way to use GF(2)? If I have a hardware LFSR (as is used for CRC calculation), can I make use of it to generate a Reed-Solomon syndrome for error correction, or am I out of luck? (I am not asking about decoding, just encoding.)

Comment: Does this mean your data words are single bits instead of 8-bit bytes?

Comment: Reed-Solomon codes over GF$(q)$ have _block lengths_ $n$ that can be $q-1$, or $q$, and possibly $q+1$ and the number of information symbols $k$ is smaller than the block length. Since the number of correctable errors is $\lfloor (n-k+1)/2\rfloor$, Reed-Solomon codes over GF(2) are not very useful.

Comment: oh, I see, so you can't arbitrarily choose the pair (255,239), for GF(256) it has to be (256 +/- 1, m).

Comment: and there's no relation between GF(256) and the Galois fields used in LFSRs? (I can never remember the technical term for those, a ring over a characteristic polynomial of degree N mod GF(2), or something like that)